# Pagination not working correctly in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, pagination

I am trying to use will_paginate for a list of items I want to display. 
There is a form with drop down selections to fetch objects by status. 
This is my controller

```
  def list
    @person = Person.find_by_id(session[:person_id])
                    params[:status] = params[:redirect_status] if params.has_key?('redirect_status')
                    @statuses = Peptide.statuses
                    @status = 'Not Ordered'
                    @status = params[:status] if params[:status] != nil || params[:status] == ''
                    @peptides = Peptide.find(:all, :conditions => ['status = ?', @status]).paginate(:per_page => 30, :page => params[:page])

    if Peptide.count.zero?
       flash[:notice] = "There are not any peptides entered"
       redirect_to :action => 'new'
    end#if zero
  end
```

This is in the view

```
  <form action="/peptide/create_spreadsheet_of_not_ordered" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <table class="sortable" cellpading="5" cellspacing="2" width="100">
   <tr class= "header-line">
    <th>SS</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Peptide</th>
    <th>Gene</th>
    <th>Submitter</th>
    <th>Created</th>
    <th>Updated</th>
    <th>Sequence</th>
    <th>Modification</th>
    <th>Vendor</th>
</tr>
<% for @peptide in @peptides.reverse %>
<tr valign = "top" class= "<%= cycle('color_one', 'color_two') %>">
<!--an error here during development likely indicates that the people table has not be repopulated or
 that no submitter primer is present for a primer-->
    <td sorttable_customkey = 0 > <%=check_box_tag "box[]", @peptide.id %>
    <td><%= @peptide.status%></td>
    <td class><%= link_to @peptide.name, :action => :report, :id => @peptide.id %></td>
    <td><%= gene_links(@peptide.genes) rescue 'Error'%></td>
    <td><%= @peptide.submitter.name rescue "" %></td>
    <td <%= sorttable_customkey_from_date(@peptide.created_at)%> >
        <%= @peptide.created_at.strftime("%b %d %Y") rescue "Unknown"%>
    </td>
    <td <%= sorttable_customkey_from_date(@peptide.updated_at)%> >
        <%= @peptide.updated_at.strftime("%b %d %Y") rescue "Unknown"%>
    </td>
    <td><%= @peptide.sequence%></td>
    <td><%= @peptide.modifications%></td>
    <td><%= @peptide.vendor%></td>
        <%= buttons() %> 
</tr>
<%end%>

   <%= will_paginate @peptides %>
</table> 
<br> 
<%= submit_tag "Create Spreadsheet"%>
```

The default list is grouped by status ordered.

however when I select any other status and submit the form the pagination links take me back to the default status.
Please help me resolve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: You might post your controller and/or forms on pastebin and link on your question

Comment: If you can paste in the full view, I'll update my answer accordingly to try and assist.

Comment: That's just your list method... what about form submission is it the same?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the view, it sounds like you need to add the current `params` as an argument to the links for the other statuses...

**Update**

Try adding the params to your status link:

`<%= link_to @peptide.name, peptide_path(@peptide, params), :action => :report, :id => @peptide.id %>`

The [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) is here.

Comment: I have added the view now.

Comment: That wont work, wrong number of arguments. Could you explain the solution a bit more. Maybe I am just confused

Comment: Yeah, I had bad code.  The first argument for `link_to` will need to be split into the link text and the link itself, the latter can handle `params`.